# How to stop my recursive division maze algorithm from plugging holes?

Tags: javascript, recursion

Relevant work is below, as well as an image. The problem becomes even more apparent when I increase the recursion (lowering the base case to < 2). I think it's happening because the 'hole' can appear in the same spot as the node but I've made them distinct as well and it didn't solve the issue. It happens on both horizontal and vertical walls.

[image: Problem visual]

```
divide: function (graph, height, width) {
      if (width < 4 || height < 4) {
        return
      }
      let vertical = Boolean(width > height)
      if (width === height) {
        const flip = Math.floor(Math.random() * 2)
        if (flip === 0) {
          vertical = true
        } else {
          vertical = false
        }
      }
      const node = graph[Math.floor(width / 2)][Math.floor(height / 2)]
      const hole = graph[Math.floor(Math.random() * width)][Math.floor(Math.random() * height)]
      if (vertical) {
        graph.forEach(row => {
          row.forEach(n => {
            if (n.row === node.row && !n.isStart && !n.isEnd && n.col !== hole.col) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                n.isWall = true
                document.getElementById(n.name).classList.add('wallNode')
              }, n.col * 20)
            }
          })
        })
        const rightGraph = []
        const leftGraph = []
        for (let i = 0; i < graph.length; ++i) {
          const rightRow = []
          const leftRow = []
          for (let j = 0; j < graph[i].length; ++j) {
            if (i > Math.floor(width / 2) && j < height) {
              rightRow.push(graph[i][j])
            } else if (i < Math.floor(width / 2) && j < height) {
              leftRow.push(graph[i][j])
            }
          }
          // It's 4AM don't judge me
          if (rightRow.length !== 0) {
            rightGraph.push(rightRow)
          }
          if (leftRow.length !== 0) {
            leftGraph.push(leftRow)
          }
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.divide(rightGraph, height, rightGraph.length)
        }, height * 5)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.divide(leftGraph, height, rightGraph.length)
        }, height * 5)
      } else {
        graph.forEach(row => {
          row.forEach(n => {
            if (n.col === node.col && !n.isStart && !n.isEnd && n.row !== hole.row) {
              setTimeout(() => {
                n.isWall = true
                document.getElementById(n.name).classList.add('wallNode')
              }, n.row * 20)
            }
          })
        })
        const upperGraph = []
        const lowerGraph = []

        for (let i = 0; i < graph.length; ++i) {
          const upRow = []
          const lowRow = []
          for (let j = 0; j < graph[i].length; ++j) {
            if (i < width && j < Math.floor(height / 2)) {
              upRow.push(graph[i][j])
            } else if (i < width && j > Math.floor(height / 2)) {
              lowRow.push(graph[i][j])
            }
          }
          upperGraph.push(upRow)
          lowerGraph.push(lowRow)
        }
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.divide(upperGraph, upperGraph[0].length, width)
        }, width * 5)
        setTimeout(() => {
          this.divide(lowerGraph, lowerGraph[0].length, width)
        }, width * 5)
      }
    },
```

Comment: First: `if (width < 4 || height < 4) return;` should be `if (width < 2 || height < 2) return;`.  Second: The `node` should be random but not on the same position has the `hole` and not on the side (0 or width-1 or height-1) unless the size is 2.  Third: You have to pass the hole's position to the lower level recursion and when you calculate the new line if it is on the same direction as the previous hole, the new hole must be beside it.

Comment: @DominiqueFortin thank you for your reply! I'll try to implement this now. I was using 4 just for an easier visual before - I intend on using 2 in the actual code but it was harder to debug for me at that level. As for your second point I tried that but not in conjunction with your third, so I'll give it a go and hopefully it works. Thank you for taking the time to help!

Comment: @DominiqueFortin if it's always a bisection through the middle (height or width / 2) then i just need to ensure that the hole does not hit that location correct? do I still need to pass the hole through?

Answer (score 0):

It's almost this. You have to keep track of all the holes in the ancestry line.

```js
var sketch = function (p) {
          with(p) {

            var queue = [];
            var Qpos = 0;
            var stack = [];
            var vertical = (myRand(2) === 0);

            p.setup = function() {
              createCanvas(330, 330);
              background(255);
              
              myRect(0,0,64,64,0);
              
              strokeWeight(1);
              stroke(0);
              //rect(1, 1, 199, 199); 
              strokeWeight(5);

              var parent = {'x':1,'y':1,'width':63,'height':63
                           ,'vertical':1, 'parent':null
                           ,'hole':{'x':0,'y':0}}; 

              stack.push(parent);
              frameRate(60);
            };
        
            p.draw = function() {
              diviseMaze();
            };

            function myRand (val) {
              return floor(Math.random() * val);
            }
            
            function diviseMaze() {
              if (stack.length <= 0) return;

              var region = stack.pop();
              
              if (region.width < 2 || region.height < 2) return;
              if (region.width === 2 && region.height === 2) return;
//             console.log(JSON.stringify(region))

              var vertical = 0;
              if (region.width === 2) {
                vertical = 0;
              } else if (region.height === 2) {
                vertical = 1;
              } else if (region.parent) {
                vertical = (region.parent.vertical+1)%2;
              }
              region.vertical = vertical;

              var node = {'x':region.x + floor((region.width + myRand(2*region.width))/4)
                         ,'y':region.y + floor((region.height + myRand(2*region.height))/4) };

              if (region.width === 2) {
                node.x = region.x + myRand(2);
              } else if (region.width === 3) {
                node.x = region.x + 1;
              }           
              if (region.height === 2) {
                node.y = region.y + myRand(2);
              } else if (region.height === 3) {
                node.y = region.y + 1;
              }           
                         
              var hole = {'x':region.x + myRand(region.width), 'y':region.y + myRand(region.height)};

              region.hole = hole;

              if (vertical) {
                var leftRegion = {};
                leftRegion.x = region.x;
                leftRegion.y = region.y;
                leftRegion.width = node.x - region.x;
                leftRegion.height = region.height;
                leftRegion.vertical = null;
                leftRegion.parent = region;
                leftRegion.hole = null;
                
                var rightRegion = {};
                rightRegion.x = region.x + leftRegion.width + 1;
                rightRegion.y = region.y;
                rightRegion.width = region.width-1 - leftRegion.width;
                rightRegion.height = region.height;
                rightRegion.vertical = null;
                rightRegion.parent = region;
                rightRegion.hole = null;

                stack.push(rightRegion);
                stack.push(leftRegion);

                {
                  let x  = (node.x);
                  let y1 = (region.y);
                  let y2 = (region.y + region.height - 1);
//                  stroke(0);
//                  line(x, y1, x, y2);
                  myLine(x, y1, x, y2, 0);
                }

                hole.x = node.x;

                // checked the holes for all the ancestry
                var r = region.parent, list = [];
                while (r) {
                  if (r.hole.x === node.x
                      && (   r.hole.y === region.y-1 
                          || r.hole.y === region.y+region.height) ) {
                    list.push(r.hole);
                  }
                  r = r.parent;
                }

                if (list.length > 1) {
                  hole.y = region.y;
                  myPoint(hole.x, hole.y, 255);
                  hole.y = region.y + region.height - 1;
                  myPoint(hole.x, hole.y, 255);
                  return;  
                }
                
                if (list.length > 0) {
                  if (list[0].y < region.y) {
                    hole.y = list[0].y + 1;
                  } else {
                    hole.y = list[0].y - 1;
                  }
                }
              } else {
                var topRegion = {};
                topRegion.x = region.x;
                topRegion.y = region.y;
                topRegion.width = region.width;
                topRegion.height = node.y - region.y;
                topRegion.vertical = null;
                topRegion.parent = region;
                topRegion.hole = null;

                var botRegion = {};
                botRegion.x = region.x;
                botRegion.y = region.y + topRegion.height + 1;
                botRegion.width = region.width;
                botRegion.height = region.height-1 - topRegion.height;
                botRegion.vertical = null;
                botRegion.parent = region;
                botRegion.hole = null;

                stack.push(botRegion);              
                stack.push(topRegion);
              
                {
                  let x1  = (region.x);
                  let x2  = (region.x + region.width - 1);
                  let y   = (node.y);
//                  stroke(0);
//                  line(x1, y, x2, y);
                  myLine(x1, y, x2, y, 0);
                }                

                hole.y = node.y;

                // checked the holes for all the ancestry
                var r = region.parent, list = [];
                while (r) {
                  if (r.hole.y === node.y
                      && (   r.hole.x === region.x-1 
                          || r.hole.x === region.x+region.width) ) {
                    list.push(r.hole);
                  }
                  r = r.parent;
                }

                if (list.length > 1) {
                  hole.x = region.x;
                  myPoint(hole.x, hole.y, 255);
                  hole.x = region.x + region.width - 1;
                  myPoint(hole.x, hole.y, 255);
                  return;  
                }
                
                if (list.length > 0) {

                  if (list[0].x < region.x) {
                    hole.x = list[0].x + 1;
                  } else {
                    hole.x = list[0].x - 1;
                  }
                }
              }

              myPoint(hole.x, hole.y, 255);
            }
            
            function myPoint (x,y,c) {
              strokeWeight(1);
              stroke(255);
              fill(c)
              rect(x*5, y*5, 5, 5);
              noFill();
            }

            function myLine (x1,y1,x2,y2,c) {
              if (x1 === x2) {
                if (y2 < y1) {
                  let temp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = temp;
                }
                for (var y = y1; y <= y2; ++y) {
                  myPoint(x1, y, c);
                } 
              } else if (y1 == y2) {
                if (x2 < x1) {
                  let temp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = temp;
                }
                for (var x = x1; x <= x2; ++x) {
                  myPoint(x, y1, c);
                } 
              } else {
                //todo
              }
            }

            function myRect (x1,y1,x2,y2,c) {
              if (x2 < x1) {
                let temp = x2; x2 = x1; x1 = temp;
              }
              if (y2 < y1) {
                let temp = y2; y2 = y1; y1 = temp;
              }
              myLine (x1+1,y1,x2,y1,c);
              myLine (x2,y1+1,x2,y2,c);
              myLine (x1,y2,x2-1,y2,c);
              myLine (x1,y1,x1,y2-1,c);
            }
           
          }
        };
        
        let node = document.createElement('div');
        window.document.getElementById('p5-container').appendChild(node);
        new p5(sketch, node);
```

```css
body {
      background-color:#efefef;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.1.9/p5.js"></script>
    <div id="p5-container"></div>
```

Comment: @Hawke Test this version.